# Availability of windows version of dev_appserver.py for python3 google app-engine

Tags: python-3.x, windows, google-app-engine

Google app-engine docs say that *"The dev_appserver tool does not support development of Python 3 apps on Windows"* (see [here]).  Yet it works with python 2.7. It is required for local testing.

Will it ever be available? And if so when?

Comment: Hi, this product question will be addressed directly by the Gcloud SDK team by opening a [Feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: We needed this functionality too so we created a patch that allows us run Python 3 Apps on Windows with dev_appserver.py. See - https://github.com/NoCommandLine/dev_appserver-python3-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish Google was clearer and more explicit about this, but I don't believe so.

With Python 3 GAE, all the GAE-specific stuff (datastore, taskqueue, etc.) has been moved to APIs and you install python libraries to use them the same way that you would interact with any third-party API.

You run your app on the command line with a local server.  You should have a file similar to this:

```
from myapp import app
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

and you just run it like this

```
python main.py
```

For interacting with GAE stuff, you should have a test project and use the test project credentials when running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Many people have recommended [Waitress](https://pylons.readthedocs.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/). It's not a GAE simulator but it helps with WSGI if you're on Windows and can't use [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).

Comment: Thanks for this. I worded my question rather poorly. What I'm really looking for is a local version of the datastore, so I don't have to create two versions in gcloud, one for testing and one for production.

Comment: We substituted Gunicorn with Waitress in a Patch we created to allow us run Python 3 Apps on Windows with dev_appserver.py. See - https://github.com/NoCommandLine/dev_appserver-python3-windows. So far, we haven't seen any issues.